# Changing what is visible based on the url hash

Tags: php, jquery, hash

Right now I have this list:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="active"><a href="#home" id="home-link"><img src="main home page/purhome.png"></a></li>
    <li id="active"><a href="#info" id="info-link"><img src="main home page/purinfo.png"></a></li>
    <li id="active"><a href="#gyms" id="gyms-link"><img src="main home page/purgyms.png"></a></li>
    <li id="active"><a href="#contact" id="contact-link"><img src="main home page/purcontact.png"></a></li>
</ul>
```

And this JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home-link").click(function(){
        $("#main_info2").hide();
        $("#main_info").show();
    });
    $("#info-link").click(function(){
        $("#main_info").hide();
        $("#main_info2").show();
    });
    $("#gyms-link").click(function(){
        $("#main_info").hide();
        $("#main_info2").show();
    });
    $("#contact-link").click(function(){
        $("#main_info").hide();
        $("#main_info2").show();
    });
});
```

When I click on the home link, the URL shows indexp.php#home, which is what i want it to show. This happens for all the links. However if i refresh the page after i click on the info link for example, the main_info div is shown, but the browser still says index.php#info. I want to read the hash somehow to show the correct div depending on what the url says.

So for example if I click on the info link, the url shows index.php#info. When I refresh it says the same thing but the main_info div shows when the main_info2 div is supposed to be showing.

```
function getHash() { 
    var hash = window.location.hash; 
    return hash.substring(1); // remove # 
}
```

So I have that code. Would I do something like this?

```
if hash = 'info' // if url says index.php#info
    show main_info2
    hide main_info

if hash = nothing // So if url says index.php
    show main_info
    hide main_info2
```

Any ideas?

EDIT**

I'm trying to do something like this to make it work:

```
var currentValue = window.location.hash.substr(1)
    $(document).ready(function() {
     $("home-link").click(function(){
        if(currentValue == "home") {
            $("#main_info2").hide();
            $("#main_info").show();
        }
     });
     $("info-link").click(function(){
        if(currentValue == "info") {    
            $("#main_info").hide();
            $("#main_info2").show();
        }
     });
    });
```

Although that is not working, can someone check the code?

Comment: When you say 'would i do something like this', that is pretty much it - why not try it?

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I'll try to put something up on jfiddle. Because i'm not exactly sure how to handle the code for this to work.

Comment: Side note, id='active' should really be class='active'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion about the different answers and problem, I came up with this solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).hashchange(function(){
 var hash = location.hash;
  if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "home") {
            $("#info-container").hide();
            $("#gyms-container").hide();
            $("#contact-container").hide();
            $("#home-container").show();
        }
          else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "info") { 
            $("#home-container").hide();
            $("#gyms-container").hide();
            $("#contact-container").hide();
            $("#info-container").show();
        }
        else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "gyms") { 
            $("#home-container").hide();
            $("#info-container").hide();
            $("#contact-container").hide();
            $("#gyms-container").show();
        }
                    else if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == "contact") { 
            $("#home-container").hide();
            $("#info-container").hide();
            $("#gyms-container").hide();
            $("#contact-container").show();
        }
    $('#list a').each(function(){
     var that = $(this);
     that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
    });
 })
 $(window).hashchange();
});
```

This work beautifully.

This uses the hashchange plugin mentioned above so make sure you insert the script into your head before using this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jQuery plugin to listen to hash changes:

https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange

I would recommend using a plugin if you want your code to work cross browser because this hasn't been standardized yet. Especially older browsers (IE6) require extensive hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is bit of code to help you get started if you use https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#home-link").click(function(){
    $("#main_info2").hide();
    $("#main_info").show();
  });
  $("#info-link").click(function(){
    $("#main_info").hide();
    $("#main_info2").show();
  });
  $("#gyms-link").click(function(){
    $("#main_info").hide();
    $("#main_info2").show();
  });
  $("#contact-link").click(function(){
    $("#main_info").hide();
    $("#main_info2").show();
  });


  $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
    url = $.deparam.fragment();
    url && $( 'a[href="#' + url + '"]' ).trigger('click');
  });
  $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: When i refresh the page still shows main_div but keeps the wrong hash, ex: index.php#info shows main_div when it is not supposed to

Comment: Ah whoops, the selector was wrong.  I removed the -link, so try it now.

Comment: It still does the same thing. I'm trying to get jsfiddle to recreate the problem

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'fragment' of undefined

Comment: Ah, for my answer to work, you have to use the full bbq plugin, not just the haschange portion.

Comment: Still does the same thing. Shows main_info on refresh while still showing index.php#info

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29869/discussion-between-bradley-hobbs-and-miah)